# Code First Migration relacionamento e Insert?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-identity, orm, migrations

Estou utilizando `UserManager` para gerenciar os usuários, estou utilizando `migration` e estou tendo problema com relacionamento.

Acontece que eu tenho a entidade `Cliente`:

```
public class Cliente : IdentityUser
{
    [NotMapped]
    public string Senha { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Pedido> Pedidos { get; set; }

    // Telefone
    [Required]
    public virtual TelefoneCliente Telefone { get; set; }

    // Documento
    [Required]
    public virtual DocumentoCliente Documento { get; set; }

    // Endereço
    [Required]

    public virtual EnderecoCliente Endereco { get; set; }
}
```

A qual possui relacionamento 1=1 com EnderecoCliente:

```
public class EnderecoCliente
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Estado Estado { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public Cidade Cidade { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string CEP { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Rua { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Numero { get; set; }

    public string Complemento { get; set; }
}
```

E a EndereçoCliente possui relação com Estado e Cidade que são dados fixos na tabela.

Quando envio a model com essa estrutura a model e seus relacionamentos estão ok, porém ele tenta incluir e efetuar um insert na tabela Cidade e Estado e obviamente gera erro pois esse registro já existe, o que precisa ser feito é apenas adicionar a referencia do id na tabela EnderecoCliente.

Codigo para inserir o cliente

```
var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(model, model.Senha);
```

Estado:

```
public class Estado
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NomeEstado { get; set; }
}
```

Cidade:

```
public class Cidade
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NomeCidade { get; set; }

    public Estado Estado { get; set; }
}
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar??

@@Edit

Segue me DBContext

```
public class EfDbContext : IdentityDbContext<Cliente>
{
    public EfDbContext() : base ("EFDbContext")
    {
        Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Produto> Produtos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Administrador> Administradores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cliente> Cliente { get; set; }

    public static EfDbContext Create()
    {
        return new EfDbContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Categoria> Categorias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MarcaVitrine> MarcaVitrine { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClubesNacionais> ClubesNacionais { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ClubesInternacionais> ClubesInternacionais { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FaixaEtaria> FaixasEtarias { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Genero> Generos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Grupo> Grupos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Marca> Marcas { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Modalidade> Modalidades { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SubGrupo> SubGrupos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProdutoVitrine> ProdutoVitrine { get; set; }
    public DbSet<QuironProduto> QuironProdutos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cor> Cores { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tamanho> Tamanhos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Estoque> Estoque { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProdutoModelo> ProdutoModelo { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Cidade> Cidade { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Estado> Estado { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Pedido> Pedidos { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ProdutoPedido> ProdutosPedidos { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Produto>().ToTable("Produtos");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Administrador>().ToTable("Administradores");

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Acredito que o problema seja porque as entidades de cidade e estado estejam detachadas do seu contexto, tente fazer o seguinte antes de chamar o `UserManager.CreateAsync(model, model.Senha)`:

```
if (UserManager.Entry(model.Cidade).State == EntityState.Detached)
    UserManager.Cidades.Atach(model.Cidade);

if (UserManager.Entry(model.Estado).State == EntityState.Detached)
    UserManager.Estados.Atach(model.Estado);
```

Não sei se isso irá resolver seu problema, pois não sei o código que você esta utilizando no seu DbContext (UserManager).

Comment: Obrigado por responder, não existe a opção Entry e também não visualizo a entidade em UserManager, nem referencias a serem adicionadas para que funcione.

Comment: UserManager nao é o DbContext e sim UserManager do asp.net.identity por isso nao tem essas opcoes